# Adding a dialog in tab in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I have made a dialog and and tabs. It is working fine. But i want to add/show a dialog in tabs. e.g if tab1 clicked dialog1 would open or show within a tab, if tab2 clicked then dialog2 would open or show within a tab. I just need help in this to how to do this stuff. Many Thanks.

Dialog and Tab.

```
<div id="dialog">
<table id="myTable" width="100%" border="0"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2 class="draggable ui-widget"> 
<thead class="ui-widget-header"> 
<tr> 
<th><strong>Symbol</strong><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s" style="position:absolute;top:15%;margin-top:-8px"></span></th> 
<th><strong>Price</strong><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s" style="position:absolute;top:15%;margin-top:-8px"></span></th> 
<th><strong>Volume</strong><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s" style="position:absolute;top:15%;margin-top:-8px"></span></th> 
<th><strong>Buy</strong><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s" style="position:absolute;top:15%;margin-top:-8px"></span></th> 
<th><strong>Sell</strong><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s" style="position:absolute;top:15%;margin-top:-8px"></span></th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
</div>

<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tabs">
<ul>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Market1</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-2">Market2</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-3">Market3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">

</div>
<div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">

</div>
<div id="tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">

</div>
```

**and this is my script.**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
   { 
    //$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();      
    //});

 $("#dialog").dialog({title:'MarketWatch',minHeight:50,width:1000});        

 } 
); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way of doing it.

But, you can achieve the same by shifting the DOM of dialog from **body** tag to the DOM of **specific** tab DOM.

1. You can use tab plugin's **select**
   or **show** event to open the
   dialog.
2. Upon **open** event of dialog, shift
   the DOM.

FYI: Make sure you use **autoOpen** option while setting up dialog.
By doing that your dialog will now be within bounds of tab and will not be visible even if user shift to another tab.

Hope that helps.